# Error when creating table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am getting the following error:

> Computed column 'OrderIssue' in table 'ProductIssue' cannot be persisted because the column is non-deterministic.

when trying to create a table with a column like

```
[OrderIssue]  AS 
(case 
    when [IssueID]=(1009) AND 
         ([Issuenumber]>=(400000) AND 
          [Issuenumber]<=(999999) OR 
          [Issuenumber]<(400000) AND 
          isnull(isnull([Enterdate],[Stagedate]),[lastClosingdate])<
                        dateadd(day,(0),'2013-04-01')) 
    then (0) 
    when [IssueID]=(1009) AND 
         ([Issuenumber]>=(400000) OR 
          [Issuenumber]<(700000) AND 
          isnull(isnull([Enterdate],[Stagedate]),[lastclosingdate])>=
                        dateadd(day,(0),'2013-04-01')) 
    then (1)  
end) PERSISTED
```

Please suggest me how to fix this.

Comment: What an absolutely bizarre design. Are you sure you need to have this in a persisted column? What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: From the msdn **A computed column is a virtual column that is not physically stored in the table, unless the column is marked PERSISTED. A computed column expression can use data from other columns to calculate a value for the column to which it belongs.**.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to use a persisted column where a view would be appropriate.

Comment: You don't have an `Else` in the `Case` statement. What happens if neither statement is true? That's why you are getting a non-deterministic error.

Answer (score 2):

Your date columns make it non-deterministic. try turning them into ints like this:

```
[OrderIssue] AS (case when [IssueID]=(1009) AND ([Issuenumber]>=(400000) AND [Issuenumber]<=(999999) OR [Issuenumber]<(400000) AND cast(convert(varchar(8),isnull(isnull([Enterdate],[Stagedate]),[lastClosingdate]),112) as int)=(400000) OR [Issuenumber]<(700000) AND cast(convert(varchar(8),isnull(isnull([Enterdate],[Stagedate]),[lastClosingdate]),112) as int)>=20130401) then (1) end) PERSISTED)
```

Or you can run this other test:

```
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tb_Test') is not null
drop table #tb_Test;

create table #tb_Test
(
IssueID int not null,
IssueNumber int not null,
Enterdate date not null,
Stagedate date not null,
lastClosingDate date not null,
[OrderIssue]  AS (
    case 
        when cast(convert(varchar(8),[Enterdate],112) as int) >= 20161222 then 0 else 1 end

) PERSISTED)

insert into #tb_Test values(1,1,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
insert into #tb_Test values(1,1,'20100101','20110101','20120101')

select *, cast(convert(varchar(8),[Enterdate],112) as int) from #tb_Test
```

cheers,